# How to get a module type from an interface?

Tags: module, ocaml

I would like to have my own implementation of an existing module but to keep a compatible interface with the existing module. I don't have a module type for the existing module, only an interface. So I can't use `include Original_module` in my interface. Is there a way to get a module type from an interface?

An example could be with the `List` module from the stdlib. I create a `My_list` module with exactly the same signature than `List`. I could copy `list.mli` to `my_list.mli`, but it does not seem very nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In some cases, you should use

```
include module type of struct include M end   (* I call it OCaml keyword mantra *)
```

rather than

```
include module type of M
```

since the latter drops the equalities of data types with their originals defined in `M`.

The difference can be observed by `ocamlc -i xxx.mli`:

```
include module type of struct include Complex end
```

has the following type definition:

```
type t = Complex.t = { re : float; im : float; }
```

which means `t` is an alias of the original `Complex.t`.

On the other hand,

```
include module type of Complex
```

has

```
type t = { re : float; im : float; }
```

Without the relation with `Complex.t`, it becomes a different type from `Complex.t`: you cannot mix code using the original module and your extended version without the `include` hack. This is not what you want usually.

Comment: Can we implement a module `my_m.ml` against an existing interface file `m.mli` if there is no corresponding implementation `m.ml` in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [RWO](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/files-modules-and-programs.html#including-modules) : if you want to include the type of a module (like List.mli) in another mli file :

```
include (module type of List)
```